# Using NumPy for discrete networking request event simulator?

Tags: python, networking, numpy, simpy

I need to simulate the requests and responses being processed by a network of routers and began small by creating a server class:

```
class NBServer:
"""Name based content server"""

def __init__(self, _id):
    self.id = _id
    self.requests = deque('x')
    self.responses = deque('x')
    self.req_load = 0 
    self.res_load = 0
    self.color = ''
    self.forwarding_table = {}
    self.content_store = {}
    self.pending_table = {}

def __str__(self):
    return 'current load: ' + str(req_load + req_load)


def request(self, content_name, requester_id):
    self.requests.append((content_name, requester_ids))
self.req_load += 1

def response(self, content_name, content_url):
    self.responses.append((content_url, destination_ids))
    return ((content_url, destination_ids))


def process(self):
    for req in self.requests:
        # Case 1: content in cache
  if content_name in self.content_store:
    return self.content_name[content_name]

  # Case 2: duplicate request exists
  elif content_name in self.pending_table:
    self.pending_table[content_name].append(requester_id)

  # Case 3: add to PT, forward to next router
  else: 
    self.pending_table[content_name] = [requester_id]

response = response.popleft()
if response:
    for dest_id in self.pending_table[content_name]:
        nodes[dest_id].response(content_name, content_url)
    del self.pending_table[content_name]
```

However, now I am getting confused on how the communication between the routers can be represented:

Any advice on how to do this with NumPy?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The first question is not programming-related.

Comment: You can either write your own simulation program or use existing simulation tools. A discrete event simulation framework for python is [SimPy](http://simpy.readthedocs.org).

Comment: A quick [introduction on SimPy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bk91DoAEcjY) is available on YouTube.